# Keeping references without modifying the state in javascript

Tags: javascript, reference, state

I have this impure code that prints two equal messages

```js
class P {
   constructor() {
        this.x  = 0
        this.y  = []
   }
}

const incrX = (p)   => { p.x = p.x + 1 ; return p }
const incrY = (p,q) => ( p.y.push(q)   ; return p }

const ps = [ new P() , new P() ]

const result = ps.map( (_,i) => i === 0 ? incrY(ps[i],ps[i+1]) : incrX(ps[i]) )

console.log( result[0].y[0] )
console.log( result[1] )
```

But using pure functions, the prints are not equal, because ps[0].y[0] keeps an old reference

```js
class P {
   constructor() {
        this.x  = 0
        this.y  = []
   }
}

const incrX = (p)   => ({ ...p , x : p.x + 1 })
const incrY = (p,q) => ({ ...p , y: [ ...p.y , q ] })

const ps = [ new P() , new P() ]

const result = ps.map( (_,i) => i === 0 ? incrY(ps[i],ps[i+1]) : incrX(ps[i]) )

console.log( result[0].y[0] )
console.log( result[1] )
```

Is there an way to keep references using something similar to the pure version ? Maybe using an array that stores references to references, is this even possible in javascript ?

Comment: Just `map` in reverse order? Or do `incrY(ps[i],incrX(ps[i+1]))`?

Comment: "*Maybe using an array that stores references to references*" - and then what, mutate those references? Doesn't sound very pure to me.

Comment: Is `ps` always a tuple (an array with two elements)?

Comment: This is just an simple example, assume that in a real situation there would be an big array with random calls to 'incrY

Comment: Not random please. What does the actual code do?

Comment: The original problem is finding the first frontier in the fast non dominated sort algorithm. Actually the problem was solved using something similar to the first example, but i was curious if there was an "purer" alternative.